# Retro 80s computer keyboard broken

Tags: digital-logic, reverse-engineering

I currently have project trying to recover a 1980s homebuild CP/M computer.

Mostly everything is working, except the keyboard.

I have trouble identifying how it's working as there is neither an internal nor external clock applied.

Of the keyboard's many lines only  +5v, GND, a3 (STROBE) and a22-25,c22-25 (Data) are connected to the terminal.

The individual keys simply pull down two lines each. (X0-11 + Y0-7)

here is the main circuit:
[image: main curcuit]

and here the keys
[image: Keys_part1]
[image: keys_part2]

As I read it the !OE of the 2716 must be low for the EEPROM to decode the input into a char code, but that line only traces to an unconnected pin (or inputs of other ICs)

Where does the clock come from?

Dito for the strobe line.

The circuit seems rather dead, wherever I put my probe at, even while typing.

Anyone able to help me debug this?

Comment: Your comment about the /OE seems at odds with the schematic you provide which shows it being driving by three-input AND gate.  Loss of data in the EPROM is not out of the question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton well, yes, I omitted the obvious, :) but I traced all three inputs and they seemed not to go anywhere.

Comment: The 3 input and gate might be a 74xx11 - look around and see if you find one.

Comment: @PeterSmith: Its IC 108, that's a SN74LS10N according to the IC list on the right.

Comment: You didn't trace very well, several of the paths feeding the AND gate go back to the /Q and/or Q outputs of the 74LS123 multivibrators.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to this all (and english is not my native language), so please excuse if I did not phrase that correctly: while tracing I also considered parts of the circuit that I (thought to) have understood and deemed irrelevant. As far as I understood the datasheet, the multivibrators need some sort of input themselves, and as they did not seem to be feeding themselves, I simply traced through them. I think they are simply used to decouple some inputs.

Comment: This is the exact type of question that is usually well received and well answered at Retrocomputing.SE. You might try asking there if answers here are not suitable. Members of Retrocomputing.SE include several engineers that actually designed hardware in the time frame your hardware was developed. https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The circuit doesn't need a clock, at least not for the key matrix.

ICs 115, 117 and 118 are priority encoders, probably 74LS148. They are strictly combinatorial circuits that generate a binary code that represents which input line is being pulled down.

The 'LS273 (124) latches the outputs of the encoders, and the comparators ('LS85, 119 and 120) above and below it are checking to see whether the current input of the latch is different from its output. This "key change" detection probably triggers the debounce logic across the bottom of the diagram, which I have not tried to analyze in detail.

The EPROM is only being used to translate from the 7-bit matrix position produced by the encoders into (probably) ASCII, based also on things like shift, ctrl, and capslock.

Comment: yes, correct, 74LS148N - the IC list is on the right. So I should be able to see the signal on those ICs at least, right?

Comment: Yes, pushing a key should pull down a pair of wires, one to the upper pair of encoders and one to the lower encoder. You should then see the outputs of the encoders change accordingly. If that much isn't happening, then there's something fundamental wrong with the key matrix itself.

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree.  This is actually a synchronous computer, composed of the EPROM, register to its left, and not one but *two* ALU chips drawn above and below.  I strongly suspect the key matrix is actively scanned, though it's not clear how that connects to the rest of the circuit.  Presumably one or more of the 74LS123's generate the clock signals.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: ALU chips? 'LS240 and 'LS241 are simple octal buffers. Or are you referring to the comparators (119 and 120, 'LS85) that are above and below the register (124, 'LS273) that latches the outputs of the encoders?

Comment: 74LS85N's - note how they are connected around the register comparing the current state to the inputs.  Granted, that is a primitive ALU but it is performing the key function of sequential computation.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: All they are doing is detecting whether the current input to the latch is different from its current output. No feedback involved. It's just a "key change" detector, and probably triggers the debounce circuitry, which I have not tried to analyze in detail.

Comment: It's possible this only sequences in brief response to an external input, but when you look at multiple drivers multiplexed with the EPROM output it becomes clear that this is a synchronous machine which sequences through a multiple states.  And what is clearly a *key matrix* could not fully distinguish keys without some sequence of drive phases, but the wiring of the matrix to the logic is not clearly documented.  There may however be an all-hot "detect any key" default that kicks it off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98281/discussion-between-dave-tweed-and-chris-stratton).

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is not a key matrix in the sense that you drive the rows and read the columns. The keys are active components that have two separate outputs, both driven low when you press them. See the details bottom left of the third sheet.